# Jenkins with Xvfb and Selenium - Firefox started but nothing executed

Tags: testing, selenium, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have a problem with Selenium under Jenkins 1.446 together with Xvfb: It looks like firefox is started correctly because I let my failing tests record screenshots. These screenshots all show the same failing page, which in my case is the starting page where the tests should begin. So I gues the selenium WebDriver commands do not arrive. What could be the reason? By the way, the tests are running perfectly on my local machine.

I'm using Firefox 9.0.1 with no specific test profile and no AddOns, Ubuntu 10.04, Senlenium 2.16.1

Log entry: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out waiting for action to finish

Thanks!

EDIT: Issue seems to be fixed by a system reboot ...

Comment: what does webdriver/selenium log say?

Comment: oh, I really missed the log-entry... here is it: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out waiting for action to finish

Comment: can you elaborate? Which action, did any actions before run succesfully?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a very similar issue with FF9.0.1 and Selenium 2.16.1 running through JUnit launched by Maven SureFire plugin run by Jenkins on a WinXP node.

**2.17.0 fixed the issue for me.  Try updating to the latest Selenium.**

Through RDP, I was able to watch the tests running.  The tests appeared to be partially blocked by a prompt from Firefox asking about collecting anonymous usage statistics.  Manually answering the prompt would allow the test to continue but because Selenium creates a new profile each time by default, the prompt would return on the next browser launch.  Running the tests locally with a pre-configured FF profile allowed me to persist that the prompt had been answered.  This isn't possible on my XP node because the tests are running as 'System'.

Selenium/WebDriver would normally take care of this for you by marking the prompt as already answered in a temporary FF profile configuration but a bug was causing the value to be set to the wrong value.  You can inject a profile configuration to the Selenium FirefoxDriver driver to pragmatically configure stuff like this prompt but the bug appeared to prevent this as well.    This has been resolved in Selenium 2.17.0 (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG see 2.17.0 WebDriver bug fixes).