# FirefoxDriver + Jenkins + Xvfb: Timed out waiting for action to finish

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, jenkins-plugins, xvfb

I'm getting a problem with running Firefox driver on Jenkins using Xvfb.

Every web driver action throws exception: `com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out waiting for action to finish`. My Xvfb configuration looks like:

[image]

The Jenkins console writes, before and after every build:

```
Xvfb starting$ Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -fbdir /jks/2013-11-06_11-50-2xvfb
Xvfb stopping
```

thus, Xvfb is running properly. FirefoxBinary is set to run with `setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":99");`.

There's a similar question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802169/jenkins-with-xvfb-and-selenium-firefox-started-but-nothing-executed), but that doesn't answer my question since I'm using webdriver version 2.34.0 and a reboot of Jenkins doesn't solve the problem too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use this command while the tests are running: `xwd -root -display :99 | convert xwd:- capture.png` (from [here](http://ralf.schaeftlein.de/2012/05/26/running-headless-webdriver-based-selenium-junit-tests-inside-jenkins-under-ubuntu-linux/)). It will take a screenshot of what's happening in Xvfb's display `:99`. In my case, it allow me to see a Firefox's error message (display in GUI in Xvfb only, not in Selenium's log). Maybe it will help you to find your bug