# Cucumber-JVM + Selenium Firefox fails on Jenkins

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I have Cucumber-JVM tests running selenium firefox webdriver.
Everything works fine running tests from eclipse, but when they run on Jenkins, the url is set correctly on the browser, but the page never loads. Jenkins is installed on a windows machine (not headless).
Probably is something simple, but I can't seem to find anything in the web that points me in the right direction.

This post ([Jenkins with Xvfb and Selenium - Firefox started but nothing executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802169/jenkins-with-xvfb-and-selenium-firefox-started-but-nothing-executed)) points into a selenium update, but I'm already using version 2.37.0...
I can see firefox window opening and there's no window or popup coming in front of firefox..

:( Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened that I was not setting the static resources right on my server. That's why no page was opening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using Firefox and Selenium (or Webdriver) required a much-older version of Firefox - the driver was simply not up to date with the latest versions of FF.

You could try using an older version, or trying to use Chrome/IE instead, to prove the issue is with FF and not your setup?

Comment: It happened that I was not setting the static resources right on my server. That's why no page was opening.